# Visual Force : Pagination & Sort Columns in Datatable

Tags: datatable, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a functionality to be implemented in Visual force page. Which consumes List and renders a Datatable.

I need some help in implementing Pagination in Datatable? Does Salesforce support any Pagination mechanisms in-built?

As well as I need help on sorting the columns of a Datatable.

Please give me inputs on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce apex:dataTable `does't support` in-built pagination.

Here are some links you can implement pagination.

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/05/pagination-using-apexdatatable-in.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/01/soql-offset-in-spring-12.html

The below link example is for `pageBlockTable`,you can use it for `apex:dataTable` as well.
http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2011/04/pagination-in-salesforce.html

Comment: Happy Salesforce coding.:)